# Javascript or operator not working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, compare

```
var strExt  = GetAttributeFromItemTable(itemTable, "Ext", "FileType");
```

I did a alert for strExt and it resolves.
    if (strExt!='wav')
    {
     // this works
    }

```
if (strExt!='wav' || strExt!='mp3')
{
// this does not work.
}
```

Comment: What is the value of strExt in all of this?

Comment: This should work under the assumption that strExt really doesn't equal 'wav' or 'mp3'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your logic is flawed:

if your variable `strExt` was equal to `'wav'` it would *not* be equal to `'mp3'`, and versa-visa.

Please explain your desired results more clearly.

I think what you're trying to say is something like (neither `'wav'` *nor* `'mp3'`):

```
if ( !( strExt == 'wav' || strExt == 'mp3' ) )
```

which is logically equivalent to (not `'wav'` *and not* `'mp3'`):

```
if ( strExt != 'wav' && strExt != 'mp3' ) )
```

Comment: trying to hide or not display the "download a copy" for all audio/video files that are in a document library of SP.

Comment: Thanks zzzBov. The first line of code worked for me. Thanks again
if ( !( strExt == 'wav' || strExt == 'mp3' ) )

Answer (score 5):

`||` says: if any condition is true, It'll return true, without looking at the ones after it.

So `true || false` is true, `false || true` is true.

In your case, you say "if strExt is not equal to **wav** and is not equal to **mp3**, then execute the code". In case that one of them is true, it executes.

I'm thinking that you're looking for the `&&` symbol. The `logical and` says "I'll return true only if every condition is true" - when it hits a false, it returns false.

What I think your code should look like:

```
if (strExt!='wav' && strExt!='mp3')
```

Comment: Great. Thanks Zirak for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the result of the second expression to be `True` regardless of the value of the string `strExt` (any extension is either not equal to "wav" or not equal to "mp3"). What do you expect?

Are you certain you don't mean a Boolean AND instead of an OR ("extension is neither 'wav' nor 'mp3'")?

Comment: I am hiding "download a copy" link whenever the file type is audio or video. (sharepoint development).

Answer (score 1):

just add the another parenthesis, like so:

```
if ((strExt!='wav') || (strExt!='mp3'))
 {
     // this does not work.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind this makes no sense wouldn't you want to do:

```
if ((strExt !== "wav") && strExt !== "mp3") {

}
```

AND instead of OR makes more sense in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into second `if`, when `strExt` is not equal to both `'wav'` and `'mp3'` you need to use an `&&` operator.

```
if (strExt!='wav' || strExt!='mp3')
```

when `strExt='wav'` => `strExt!='wav'` = false;  `strExt!='mp3'` = true => false or true = true and gets into `if` statement and is the case is similar when `strExt='mp3'`  .